# How to Add Custom headers on swagger-api-explorer

Tags: cors, swagger-ui

I am trying to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in header. To do so I added this lines:

```
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("headerKey", apiKeyAuth);
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("headerKey", new  SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('Allow-Access-Control-Origin', '*', "header"));
```

Unfortunately, I get this when I explore the request header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, developer_key, access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
```

There is no extra custom header added in the request header. It is adding my `_access-control-allow-origin_` as a value into `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

I want to add this `_access-control-allow-origin_` as a new custom header like:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, developer_key
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
```

Can anyone suggest me what am I doing wrong, or what should I do extra to get this work?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to enable CORS by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from Swagger UI a.k.a the client side. However, you should enable CORS on the server side. [Swagger UI Wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#enabling-cors) also points to that:

> The method of enabling CORS depends on the server and/or framework you use to host your application.

*A short background about CORS:*
When a web browser and/or a JavaScript toolkit wants to send an HTTP request to a host/server that is on another domain, it adds some CORS-related headers such as `Access-Control-Request-Method` (for the request HTTP method) and `Access-Control-Request-Header` (for a list of headers in the HTTP request). On the server side, if the request method and the headers are allowed, the server will send an HTTP response back that has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Browsers will block the responses that don't have this header.

As for why the header is showing up in `Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, developer_key, access-control-allow-origin`, the reason is that your browser or JS toolkit is treating `access-control-allow-origin` as a regular custom header that your code is sending to the server. And probing the server, if the HTTP request is valid.

You can learn more about CORS here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You can also refer to this [`website`](http://enable-cors.org/) to learn more about how to enable CORS on your server.